# Align textView center horizontally

Tags: android

[image]

I want the controller textView to be centre of the app. I used android:gravity="center" but doesn't help.
My code is

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CONTROLLER"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `android:gravity="center"` in the Layout and also `android:layout_height="match_parent"`to the center the TextView in the whole View.
and `android:gravity="center_horizontal" to centralize it horizontaly.`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CONTROLLER"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

and also the textSize should be meausured in sp not dp.